# SharePoint 2013, Metadata with extra information

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, administration

I need to have Custom list that will contains list of People (not SP users) with basic information and to have one metadata field with extra information attached (years).

Example:

```
FirstName |  LastName |  Address   | Technology (metadata multiple information) + years 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
John      |  Smith    |  address 1 | C# - 4 years
          |           |            | Javascript - 3 years
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Joe       |  Doe      |  address 2 | C# - 2 years
          |           |            | VB.NET - 1 year
          |           |            | JQuery - 1 year
```

Is it possible to achieve this kind of scenario without development?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Rating scale field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldRatingScale%28v=office.15%29.aspx) might be a good candidate for storing Technology values, but this field is supported in `Surveys` only.

About Rating scale field:

> A rating scale question consists of a question and sub-questions that
>   are rated on a scale such as 1 to 5.

Survey form with Rating scale field is shown on picture below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a managed metadata store in Central admin and no need for custom development.

Step 1 
adding the terms C# ,VB.NET,JQuery .Another term store with the values for years.

Step 2 : 
When you create the list create column with "metadata" type and

Step 3 " select multiple values which you create in Step 1.

Comment: I don't see how to implement this. 1) I Created 2 term stores. Step 2) I create column of type metadata, but Step 3) I don't see how I can select multiple term stores?

Comment: http://sureshpydi.blogspot.com/2013/04/sharepoint-2013-create-term-set-terms.html

Comment: Ok, I know how to create Term Stores and how to create Column of type Metadata, and how to assign a store to a column. Please check again my problem. I need to connect 2 terms together (Technology and Years) and to do that multiple times

Comment: I would prefer a calculated column . But you cannot use a Managed Metadata Column for calculated fields. So if you have a requirement to do a calculated field you will need to use another column type. A designer solution is possible . PS : http://sympmarc.com/2012/11/09/displaying-managed-metadata-column-values-in-an-email-sent-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/